# How to insert code before the </li> end tag for wp_list_pages?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to insert another automatically generated UL before the  end tag for the following code:

```
<?php wp_list_pages('include=4&title_li='); ?>
```

I want it to function just like link_after only it would have to be li_after (unftortunately doesn't exist?

Do you have any idea how I can do this?

Comment: Create a custom walker class - http://badfunproductions.com/create-a-custom-walker-class-to-extend-wp_list_pages/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this in your functions.php:

```
class List_Append extends Walker_Page
{
    function end_el(&$output, $page, $depth)
    {
        $output .= "</li>";
        $output .= "your_ul_here";
    }
}
```

Then call like so:

```
wp_list_pages(array('include' => '4', 'title_li' => '', 'walker' => new List_Append()));
```